# Search contact with part of phone number

Tags: android

I try to search contacts with the next uri:

```
Uri.withAppendedPath(Phone.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(query))
```

It works for partial numbers but only when this part is the beginning of the number. How to look for contact with the middle part?